# Read command after command substitution returns immediately in git-bash but not in Cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin, git-bash

I have a bash script that I use as a helper script for generating diffs in git-bash. The script makes use of a program I wrote called `menu` that lists choices passed in as command line args, and prompts you to choose one. In this case, the choices are git commits. I call the `menu` program using command substitution in my bash script, like so:

```
commit=$(menu --title "Choose a commit:" "CommitA" "CommitB" "CommitC")
```

The `menu` program is using `fgets(line, 256, stdin);` to read the user's selection, and it prints the choices to `stderr` so that they won't be captured by the command substitution in my script. When the user selects one of the options, `menu` prints that option to `stdin` so it can be captured by the command substitution. In my example code below, I omit the printing to `stdout`, because it has no effect on the behavior of the subsequent `read` command. Afterwards, I prompt the user for an output directory using the `read` builtin:

```
read -p "Enter the output directory: " outputDir
```

For some reason, when I run this in Cygwin, it works fine, but when I run it in git-bash, the `read` hits EOF immediately and does not wait for me to enter text.

The code for the `menu` program is too long to list here, so I've boiled the whole thing down to a  minimal reproducible example. Here's the example script and C code. In the example, instead of calling my `menu` program, I wrote a small C program called `prompt`, which just prints a simple prompt to `stderr` and then does an `fgets`, which more or less simulates what the `menu` program is doing.

```
> cat test.sh
x=$(./prompt)
read -p "read> " x

> cat prompt.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   char line[256];

   fprintf(stderr, "fgets> ");
   fflush(stderr);
   fgets(line, 256, stdin);

   return 0;
}
```

When I run this example, I get different results in Cygwin than I do in git-bash:

```
# Cygwin
> ./test.sh
fgets> foo
read> bar

# git-bash
> ./test.sh
fgets> foo
read>       # <== read returns immediately and does not wait for input
```

I thought perhaps the command substitution was leaving a character stuck in the `stdin` buffer, but doing `echo -n "$x" | wc -c` returns 0, which indicates no input was read. In any case, after the `read`, everything starts working as expected again. For instance, if I add a dummy `read` right after the command substitution, then the script works as expected in git-bash:

```
> cat test.sh
x=$(./prompt)
# Dummy read to clear stdin
read
# This works fine now in git-bash
read -p "read> " x
```

I am at a loss to explain this difference in behavior. In the meantime, I have found a workaround, which is to use the `-t timeout` option of `read` for the dummy read, with a timeout of 0.1 seconds, so that it will consume the extraneous `EOF` from `stdin` without requiring the user to hit Enter to get past the dummy read:

```
x=$(./prompt)
# Dummy read using timeout
read -t 0.1
read -p "read> " x
```

It seems like this should just work though, without the dummy read.

Here are the `bash` versions involved:

```
# Cygwin
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

# git-bash
> bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I also tested this example on Ubuntu 20.04, running bash 5.0.17, and it works fine.

Comment: I bet it has something to do with Windows CRLF line endings.

Comment: @Shawn : How would this explain the difference between git-bash and Cygwin?

Comment: I presume you compiled `prompt.c` in `Cygwin`. Can you try to compile it in `git-bash` ?

Comment: @Philippe I compiled it in both. It didn't make any difference.

Comment: Your `prompt.c` and original `test.sh` worked as is in both my cygwin and git-bash which is the same version as yours : 4.4.23(1)-release

Comment: @Philippe That's really strange. I'm not sure what to make of that. It does rule out a few possible explanations though. Thanks for taking the time to try it out.